# C++ on Unix: Differences in threading libraries?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, boost, c++11

What are the differences in using boost:thread, Posix Thread library and the new C++11 multithreading library, especially in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much nothing, because `boost::thread` is a thin wrapper on top of POSIX threads, and the same can be expected from C++11 multithreading implementations on *nix.

Comment: What part of C++11 are you talking about? It offers much more in terms of functionality than either Boost or POSIX. It’s certainly more than just a thin wrapper.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I am talking about the union of the featureset that `boost::thread`, POSIX threads and `std::thread` have to offer. The performance of additional parts are though to compare with libraries that don't offer them in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

boost::thread should be a wrapper around POSIX. Just read the spec and C++11 offers the same features.